# Printing shipping labels creates the following error: Add Package Create Packages The XML document is well formed but the document is not valid

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, labels

I get the following code back from UPS:

```
[result] =>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ShipmentConfirmResponse>
  <Response>
    <ResponseStatusCode>0</ResponseStatusCode>
    <ResponseStatusDescription>Failure</ResponseStatusDescription>
    <Error>
      <ErrorSeverity>Hard</ErrorSeverity>
      <ErrorCode>10002</ErrorCode>
      <ErrorDescription>The XML document is well formed but the document is not valid</ErrorDescription>
      <ErrorLocation>
                <ErrorLocationElementName>AccessRequest/AccessLicenseNumber</ErrorLocationElementName>
      </ErrorLocation>
    </Error>
  </Response>
</ShipmentConfirmResponse>
[__pid] => 17123
)
```

The XML I am sending is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <AccessLicenseNumber></AccessLicenseNumber>
  <UserId></UserId>
  <Password></Password>
    </AccessRequest>
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <ShipmentConfirmRequest xml:lang="en-US">
      <Request>
            <RequestAction>ShipConfirm</RequestAction>
            <RequestOption>nonvalidate</RequestOption>
          </Request>
      <Shipment>
        <Description>Botron B62350 Green Dissipative 2 L</Description>
        <Shipper>
      <Name>Company name</Name>
      <AttentionName>first last</AttentionName>
      <ShipperNumber></ShipperNumber>
      <PhoneNumber>9999999999</PhoneNumber>
      <Address>
          <AddressLine1>21601 N 21st Ave</AddressLine1>
          <AddressLine2></AddressLine2>
          <City>Phoenix</City>
          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
          <PostalCode>85027</PostalCode>
          <StateProvinceCode>AZ</StateProvinceCode>
          </Address>
    </Shipper>
        <ShipTo>
      <AttentionName>first last</AttentionName>
          <CompanyName>test</CompanyName>
      <PhoneNumber>6236809173</PhoneNumber>
      <Address>
          <AddressLine1>11829 W Monte Lindo Ln</AddressLine1>
          <AddressLine2></AddressLine2>
          <City>Sun City</City>
          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
          <PostalCode>85373</PostalCode>
          <StateProvinceCode>AZ</StateProvinceCode>
          </Address>
    </ShipTo>
        <Service><Code>GND</Code></Service>
        <Package>
      <Description>Botron B62350 Green Dissipative 2 L</Description>
      <PackagingType><Code>2c</Code></PackagingType>
      <PackageWeight>
            <Weight>3</Weight>
            <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>LBS</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
          </PackageWeight>
      <ReferenceNumber><Code>02</Code>
            <Value>Order #100000002 P1</Value>
          </ReferenceNumber>
    </Package>
        <PaymentInformation>
      <Prepaid>
            <BillShipper>
          <AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
        </BillShipper>
          </Prepaid>
    </PaymentInformation>
      </Shipment>
  <LabelSpecification>
        <LabelPrintMethod><Code>GIF</Code></LabelPrintMethod>
        <LabelImageFormat><Code>GIF</Code></LabelImageFormat>
      </LabelSpecification>
</ShipmentConfirmRequest>
```

I see that AccessLicenseNumber is blacnk, as is user ID and password and shipper number. But I don't see a place to put those things in the magento shipping settings page so I am a bit confused if they are even required and / or if that's the reason I am getting errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the XML UPS Type on the shippping settings page, then input your proper credentials.